# Is it possible to continue reading from where receiver stopped in EventHub with Python?

Tags: python, azure, commit, offset, azure-eventhub

I'm using the official azure-eventhub lib for reading events from a topic from EventHub. I want to be able when the receiver stop reading, EventHub to keep the last offset of my receiver group, so when I will start reading again I can start from where I stopped. That is in Kafka done with the commit policy, but I can't find anything similar in the azure-eventhub lib. Is there anything like this in the azure-eventhub or any other python lib for eventhub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Event Processor Host** in python to set the checkpoint to blob storage.

The detailed sample code is [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/eph.py) in github, we're using it for checkpoint purpose.

Before using **Event Processor Host**, you should have/create an [azure storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-quickstart-create-account?tabs=azure-portal#create-a-storage-account-1) which is used to save the checkpoint. And [create a container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-portal#create-a-container) inside that azure storage account. The `storage account` / `account key` / `container` are used [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-python/blob/master/examples/eph.py#L89) in the sample code.

In the sample, this line of code `context.checkpoint_async()` is used to set checkpoint.

Please let me know if you have more questions about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use azure-eventhub v5 to achieve the goal. The v5 sdk integrates the functionality to store checkpoint in Azure Storage Blob in an easy way.

azure-eventhub v5 has been GAed in 2020 Jan, and the latest version is v5.2.0

It's available on pypi: https://pypi.org/project/azure-eventhub/

Please check the [sample code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/samples/sync_samples/receive_batch_with_checkpoint.py) to see how this could be achieved in v5:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
# Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

"""
An example to show receiving events from an Event Hub with checkpoint store doing checkpoint by batch.
In the `receive_batch` method of `EventHubConsumerClient`:
If no partition id is specified, the checkpoint_store are used for load-balance and checkpoint.
If partition id is specified, the checkpoint_store can only be used for checkpoint without load balancing.
"""

import os
import logging
from azure.eventhub import EventHubConsumerClient
from azure.eventhub.extensions.checkpointstoreblob import BlobCheckpointStore

CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["EVENT_HUB_CONN_STR"]
EVENTHUB_NAME = os.environ['EVENT_HUB_NAME']
STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_CONN_STR"]
BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME = "your-blob-container-name"  # Please make sure the blob container resource exists.

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def on_event_batch(partition_context, event_batch):
    log.info("Partition {}, Received count: {}".format(partition_context.partition_id, len(event_batch)))
    # put your code here
    partition_context.update_checkpoint()


def receive_batch():
    checkpoint_store = BlobCheckpointStore.from_connection_string(STORAGE_CONNECTION_STR, BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME)
    client = EventHubConsumerClient.from_connection_string(
        CONNECTION_STR,
        consumer_group="$Default",
        eventhub_name=EVENTHUB_NAME,
        checkpoint_store=checkpoint_store,
    )
    with client:
        client.receive_batch(
            on_event_batch=on_event_batch,
            max_batch_size=100,
            starting_position="-1",  # "-1" is from the beginning of the partition.
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    receive_batch()
```

We also provide a [migration guide from v1 to v5](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhub/migration_guide.md) to migrate the program.